# Tag-Request: dividing boats into

Tags: discussion, tagging, tags

While keeping the tag [boat] for genereal purpose we could consider to add tags as:

<strike>[motor-boat] [rowing-boat] [sail-boat]</strike>.

**edit** ([answer](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/270/741) by: [Kevin](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/users/18/kevin)): [motorboats](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorboats) [rowboats](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rowboats) [sailboats](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailboats)

As the site is young and so not many questions are tagged [boats], I suspect it will grow in time. There is a significant different in handling, maintenance, rules and interests.

For the canou there is already a tag.

Answer (score 5):

I agree they are different enough that they should have different tags, but I think they should be [motorboats](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorboats) [sailboats](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailboats) and [rowboats](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rowboats).

Comment: I agree as well

Answer (score 2):

I agree that there should be some distinction, but note that there is a lot of difference between sailing on a river in a 6ft sailboat and sailing on the ocean in a 50ft er.

In addition, there is much in common with the different boat types, so there is no reason not to have "boats" (sorry, I don't know how to make buttons).

In reality, what do we suppose might go in a "sailboats" category? If it's matters to do with "sailing" then maybe "sailing" is the better tag.